# Is going from $V_{\text{L}} = L \frac{di_{\text{L}}}{dt}$ to $\frac{ V_{\text{L}} } {i_L} = L \frac{d}{dt}$ allowed?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

The Laplace transform of $\frac{d}{dt} f(t)$ would be sF(s), when f(0)=0, which is something you can find in a Laplace transform table.

If there is a rule that prohibits mathematical operations from $v_{\text{L}}(t) = L \frac{di_{\text{L}}(t)}{dt}$ to $\frac{ V_{\text{L}} (t) } {i_L (t)} = L \frac{d}{dt}$ and do the **Laplace transform** after that to make the result of this Laplace transform equal to sL, because $i_L(t)$ is not a constant, what would be wrong with this reasoning: The laplace transform of $v_L(t)$ is $V_L(s)$, the Laplace transform of $i_L(t)$ is $I_L(s)$, the Laplace transform of $V_{\text{L}}(t) = L \frac{di_{\text{L}}(t)}{dt}$  is $V_{\text{L}}(s) = L \cdot s \cdot I_L(s)$, so $\frac{V_L (s)}{I_L (s)} = L \cdot s $ and the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{V_L (s)}{I_L (s)} = L \cdot s $ is $\frac{ V_{\text{L}}(t) } {i_L (t)} = L \frac{d}{dt}$?

Comment: @moo It was more about the Laplace transform than about a circuit, I added some more details.

Comment: $2t$ is the derivative of $t^2$, i.e. $2t = \frac{d}{dt} t^2$, what does it mean that $\frac{2t}{t^2} =  \frac{d}{dt} $ ? nothing. because $ \frac{d}{dt} $ is an operator, not a function

Comment: there is also the fact that the Laplace transform is a linear operator ( as $\frac{d}{dt}$) but there is no formula for the Laplace transform of $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$ in term of $F(s)$ and $G(s)$. So what I mean is : you have to prove everything if you want to understand something as the Laplace transform (you can't just play with formulas without understanding them)

Answer (score 1):

No: Recalling the quotient rule $$\frac{d}{dx}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac{\frac{df}{dx}g(x)-f(x)\frac{dg}{dx}}{g(x)^2}=\dfrac{1}{g(x)}\dfrac{df}{dx}-\frac{f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2},$$ we conclude that $\dfrac{1}{g(x)}\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) \neq \dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ unless $g(x)=$ const.

Comment: In that case, what would be wrong with this reasoning: The laplace transform of $v_L(t)$ is $V_L(s)$, the Laplace transform of $i_L(t)$ is $I_L(s)$, the Laplace transform of $V_{\text{L}}(t) = L \frac{di_{\text{L}}(t)}{dt}$  is $V_{\text{L}}(s) = sL \cdot I_L(s)$, so the Laplace transform of $\frac{ V_{\text{L}}(t) } {i_L}(t) = L \frac{d}{dt}$  is $\frac{V_L (s)}{I_L (s)} = sL $?

Comment: @Modap no, I think you have a terrible misunderstanding of derivatives and of the Laplace transform ${}{}$

Comment: @user1952009 What would be the misunderstanding? The Laplace transform of $\frac{d}{dt} f(t)$ would be sF(s), when f(0)=0, which is something you can find in a Laplace transform table.

Comment: @Modap the misunderstanding is exactly here. So no $d/dt$ doesn't have a Laplace transform, because $d/dt$ is a (convolution) operator, not a function

Comment: @user1952009 that's not a misunderstanding. Almost every Laplace transform table contains an entry from which you can conclude that Laplace transform of $\frac{d}{dt} f(t)$ would be sF(s), when f(0)=0

Comment: @Modap ok, prove it

Comment: @user1952009 It is listed as entry 35 in this Laplace transform table: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf

Comment: @Modap lol, I meant prove that formula (and tks I know the derivatives and the Laplace transform, that's why I can tell you messed up everything)

Comment: Could you please take this to a chat room? This back and forth doesn't really bear on the answer I've written.

Comment: @Semiclassical could you please help me explaining him he has to read a real analysis course

Comment: @user1952009 I don't have access to the chatroom, but what's your point of all this "You are so wrong, but I'm not going to tell you why it is wrong"? You can find the Proof of Laplace Transform of the first derivative on the internet http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceXform/FwdLaplace/LaplaceProps.html#First_ http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/advance-engineering-mathematics/laplace-transforms-derivatives And there's nothing unexpected in this proof.